# Change the name of the editor itunes app store

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

How to change the developer name in the appstore. see attached image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but it can't be edited after creation.You can edit other information but not the first name last name and email address through the developer account.

Comment: Are you sure about that one? damn, i want to know if when i create another app it will still use the same name?

Do you think that sending an email to apple can help?

thanks

Comment: You can try it yourself... I have tried it and couldn't edit the name.All the Apps issued under this account would show that name...

Comment: I think sending a mail to Apple is the only option you have at this point of time...